# jQuery and WebPy to create link which selects a drop down option

Tags: jquery, web.py, html-select

This is the code I am using for what I want to achieve http://jsfiddle.net/HFvRs/

```
<form action="" method="post" name="paramform" id="paramform">
<select id="param" name="Param">
<option value="select">select</option>
<option value="startp">startp</option>
</select>
<a href="#paramform" data-select="startp">startp 1 </a>
```

and

```
var $select = $('#param');
$('a[href="#paramform"]').click(function () {
$select.val($(this).data('select') );
});
```

I've linked the javascript externally (so no problems with the '$') in my static folder. The script tags are in the head tag of my base file. I don't get any errors, and when I click the link to select option, the page just jumps to the drop down instead of changing the option.

Answer (score 0):

Use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) in link click to stop the default behavior of the link.

```
$('a[href="#paramform"]').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $select.val($(this).data('select') );
});
```